# Keras gives nan when training categorical LSTM sequence-to-sequence model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to write a Keras model (using the Tensorflow backend) that uses an LSTM to predict labels for sequences like you would in a part-of-speech labeling task. The model I have written returns `nan` as a loss for all training epochs and for all label predictions. I suspect I have my model configured incorrectly, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The full program is here.

```
from random import shuffle, sample
from typing import Tuple, Callable

from numpy import arange, zeros, array, argmax, newaxis


def sequence_to_sequence_model(time_steps: int, labels: int, units: int = 16):
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=units, input_shape=(time_steps, 1), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(labels)))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    return model


def labeled_sequences(n: int, sequence_sampler: Callable[[], Tuple[array, array]]) -> Tuple[array, array]:
    """
    Create training data for a sequence-to-sequence labeling model.

    The features are an array of size samples * time steps * 1.
    The labels are a one-hot encoding of time step labels of size samples * time steps * number of labels.

    :param n: number of sequence pairs to generate
    :param sequence_sampler: a function that returns two numeric sequences of equal length
    :return: feature and label sequences
    """
    from keras.utils import to_categorical

    xs, ys = sequence_sampler()
    assert len(xs) == len(ys)
    x = zeros((n, len(xs)), int)
    y = zeros((n, len(ys)), int)
    for i in range(n):
        xs, ys = sequence_sampler()
        x[i] = xs
        y[i] = ys
    x = x[:, :, newaxis]
    y = to_categorical(y)
    return x, y


def digits_with_repetition_labels() -> Tuple[array, array]:
    """
    Return a random list of 10 digits from 0 to 9. Two of the digits will be repeated. The rest will be unique.
    Along with this list, return a list of 10 labels, where the label is 0 if the corresponding digits is unique and 1
    if it is repeated.

    :return: digits and labels
    """
    n = 10
    xs = arange(n)
    ys = zeros(n, int)
    shuffle(xs)
    i, j = sample(range(n), 2)
    xs[j] = xs[i]
    ys[i] = ys[j] = 1
    return xs, ys


def main():
    # Train
    x, y = labeled_sequences(1000, digits_with_repetition_labels)
    model = sequence_to_sequence_model(x.shape[1], y.shape[2])
    model.summary()
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, verbose=2)
    # Test
    x, y = labeled_sequences(5, digits_with_repetition_labels)
    y_ = model.predict(x, verbose=0)
    x = x[:, :, 0]
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        print(' '.join(str(n) for n in x[i]))
        print(' '.join([' ', '*'][int(argmax(n))] for n in y[i]))
        print(y_[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My feature sequences are arrays of 10 digits from 0 to 9. My corresponding label sequences are arrays of 10 zeros and ones where zero indicates a unique digit and one indicates a repeated digit. (The idea is to create a simple classification task that incorporates long-distance dependencies.)

Training looks like this

```
Epoch 1/20
 - 1s - loss: nan
Epoch 2/20
 - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 3/20
 - 0s - loss: nan
```

And all the label array predictions look like this

```
[[nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]]
```

So clearly something is wrong.

The features matrix passed to `model.fit` is of dimensionality `samples` × `time steps` × `1`. The labels matrix is of dimensionality `samples` × `time steps` × `2`, where the 2 comes from a one-hot encoding of the labels 0 and 1.

I'm using a [time-distributed dense layer](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) to predict sequences, following the Keras documentation and posts like [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611006/timedistributeddense-vs-dense-in-keras-same-number-of-parameters). To the best of my knowledge, the model topology defined in `sequence_to_sequence_model` above is correct. The model summary looks like this

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 16)            1152      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 10, 2)             34        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,186
Trainable params: 1,186
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Stack Overflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232782/nan-loss-when-training-regression-network) make it sound like `nan` results are an indicator of numeric problems: runaway gradients and whatnot. However, since I am working on a tiny set data and every number that comes back from my model is a `nan`, I suspect I'm not seeing a numeric problem, but rather a problem with how I have constructed the model.

Does the code above have the right model/data shape for sequence-to-sequence learning? If so, why do I get `nan`s everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

By default the `Dense` layer has no activation. If you specify one, the `nan`s go away. Change the following line in the code above.

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(labels, activation='softmax')))
```

Comment: But how about if it is a regression model? I am seeing above same issue sometimes when I run my model (and sometimes not). Nans come from 1st  epoch itself, so this is not a cause of exploding or vanishing gradients. Mine is a regression model

Answer (score 0):

If the model weights and the loss become NaN quickly, this is an indicator for exploding gradients.
I would add a batch normalization after the LSTM layer and check if it helps.

```
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

# [...]
model.add(LSTM(units=units, input_shape=(time_steps, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

For me (on a categorical classification problem) batch normalization solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the predictions before training. If the model already gives you NaNs, then there could be something wrong in you data too:

- Check the `dtype`, try double precision (i.e. `tf.float64`).
- Make sure you data is sound.

Otherwise, you could:

- Add `LayerNormalization` after the `LSTM`.
- Try a different kernel initializer, and/or with one with smaller variance.
- A lower learning rate (Adam's default is 0.001).
- Gradient clipping: when you compile the model, do `model.compile(..., optimizer=Adam(clipnorm=1.0))`. Specifying a global norm of `1` is usually a good default.
- Change the optimizer's epsilon value.
- Change optimizer, like something simpler as `SGD`.
- Try to define or edit the loss function, it's possible the default `categorical_crossentropy` doesn't handle well 3D tensors.