# Why is TimeDistributed not needed in my Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I know there are a lot of questions to this topic, but I don't understand why in my case both options are possible.
My input shape in the LSTM is (10,24,2) and my hidden_size is 8.

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, stateful = True, 
               batch_input_shape=((10, 24, 2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
```

Why is it possible to either add this line below:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2))) # Option 1
```

or this one:

```
model.add(Dense(2)) # Option 2
```

Shouldn't `Option 2` lead to a compilation error, because it expects a two-dimensional input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case the 2 models you define are identical.

This is caused by the fact that you use the `return_sequences=True` parameter which means that the `Dense` layer is applied to every timestep just like `TimeDistributedDense` but if you switch to `False` then the 2 models are not identical and an error is raised in case of `TimeDistributedDense` version though not in the `Dense` one.

A more thorough explanation is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44616780/3584765) also to a similar situation.