# What is the effect of using TimeDistributed layer wrapper?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Consider the following two models:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GRU, Dense, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(batch_shape=(None, None, 100)) 
gru_out = GRU(32, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
dense = Dense(200, activation='softmax')
decoder_pred = TimeDistributed(dense)(gru_out)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoder_pred)
model.summary()
```

with the output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru (GRU)                    (None, None, 32)          12768     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, None, 200)         6600      
=================================================================
Total params: 19,368
Trainable params: 19,368
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And the second model:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GRU, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(batch_shape=(None, None, 100)) 
gru_out = GRU(32, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
decoder_pred = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(gru_out)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoder_pred)
model.summary()
```

with the output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, None, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_1 (GRU)                  (None, None, 32)          12768     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 200)         6600      
=================================================================
Total params: 19,368
Trainable params: 19,368
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My question is, is the `TimeDistributed` layer wrapper doing anything to the first model? Are these two different in any aspect (considering that their total number of params are identical)?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611006/timedistributeddense-vs-dense-in-keras-same-number-of-parameters